# Tkinter change text color while writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, i want to change text color while writing, i tried this code which did nothing apparently:

```
def text_color():
     txt.tag_configure('color',foreground='red')
     txt.tag_add('color','1.0',END)
```

for example, when i am writing a text in Text() widget field by default it is black:

[image]

i want to write in text field with red color:

[image]

Comment: What class is `txt`? Also, what do you mean with "while writing"? Do you want different words to have different colors, or should the color of the entire text change randomly over time?

Comment: @tobias_k the default color is black when writing in tex field, i just want to change the color text to red, also txt is an object for ```Text() ``` widget

Comment: Please have a look at the help center's [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question, we need more details to understand what you want to do and what is not working.

Comment: When do you call that function? Before or after inserting the text?

Comment: @j_4321 i have edited my post to clarify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the text color to red in the whole text widget, don't use tags, use the foreground option:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root, foreground='red')
txt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, i really got confused with tags, and forgot that ``Text()`` widget has a foreground option ( i thought it only has background).

Comment: @ghazigamer _TIP:_ most of the widgets with texts has `background` aswell as `foreground`

Comment: *Other TIP*: if unsure about a widget's options, they can be listed with the `.keys()` method.

Answer (score -1):

I have a running project, `tag_config` work for me. The other content is the same as yours.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: @j_4321 i agree with you.

Comment: @j_4321 isnt 50 points the minimum rep fr comments?

Comment: @CoolCloud Maybe but that does not mean that users with less reputations should post comments as answer. I just posted the above comment so that the user won't be surprised if their post gets deleted.

Comment: @j_4321 Yes i agree with that!!